# What search routine should I use to match the exact entries of my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html-table, filtering

I am looking to find exact search when typing in a table. Right now I have it appear if any of the input matches then have those appear. Is there a way to only pull those exact matches (e.g. if I enter "IT", I wouldn't want "Monitoring" or "Website Design" to appear).

```
<html>
    <div class="rostercontent">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search" title="Search">
</html>


<script> function filterTable(event) {
    var filter = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
    var rows = document.querySelector("#rosterTable tbody").rows;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var firstCol = rows[i].cells[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var fourthCol = rows[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var fifthCol = rows[i].cells[4].textContent.toUpperCase();

        if (firstCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || fourthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || fifthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            rows[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', filterTable, false);
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add the `#rosterTable` element to your HTML? And what is `myFunction` doing?

Comment: If "IT" should not return "Monitoring" or "Website Design" for example, i would recommend removing `toUpperCase()`